# Apache throwing 404 for a file in var/www folder

Tags: php, apache

I have the following php file (try.php) inside my `/var/www folder`. I am operating a mac.

```
$html = "testing print";
$handle = printer_open();
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_write($handle, $html);
printer_close($handle);
```

I have apache and php installed . If I execute the command.

```
apachectl -version
```

I get

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 10 2013 22:09:38
```

Similarly executing for php version I get

```
PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I restart my server with the following command.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

The command returns on the console without printing anything. After that I hit the url.

```
http://localhost/try.php
```

This gives me a 404 error.

> The requested URL /try.php was not found on this server.

I have also given read, write and execute permissions to the `/var/www` folder.

Any ideas what I get this error.

The document root configuration in http.conf file is as follows.

```
<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Take a look in file .htaccess

Comment: What is the `DocumentRoot` configured in Apache config file?

Comment: Its DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should find the document root.

By running the command below in the shell, you should get the path of the apache config file:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

then pick your favourite editor, and search for the `DocumentRoot` parameter inside of it.
By default the `DocumentRoot` defines the path of your public data. Whatever is inside of that folder, is visible by others, outside the server.

For more information, I'd recommend to read the apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put the file to the /var/www/**html** folder

Comment: Not necessarily true. Depends on configuration.

Comment: At least add some restricting information as on what distribution is it the default setting